# Who are the Pokémon on the decoration in the Viridian City Pokémon Center?

Tags: pokemon

In the Pokémon anime episode 2: *Pokémon Emergency!*, Ash sees the following decoration in the Viridian City Pokémon Center:

[image]

[image]

Ash tells Professor Oak via videophone that the blue Pokémon in the top right corner is the Pokémon that he saw at the end of the first episode ([Ho-Oh](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ho-Oh_(anime))), although he didn't know its name. Personally, I think the one in the top left looks more like Ho-Oh, plus it is red which would match its Fire type, but what do I know.

If the top right one is Ho-Oh as Ash said, what are the other Pokémon in this decoration?

Comment: The blue one (top right) is Articuno, which ash Ash mistakes for Ho-Oh. But it is interesting that Ho-Oh, a 2nd Generation Pokémon, appears in the pilot of the first season. The red one (top left) is actually Moltres.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

These are the four "[Legendary](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Legendary_Pok%C3%A9mon)" pokemon that were known at the start of Season 1; [Zapdos](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Zapdos_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), [Articuno](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Articuno_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), [Moltres](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Moltres_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) as well as [Arcanine](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Arcanine_(Pok%C3%A9mon)). Note that while Arcanine isn't one of the official "Legendary" pokemon, its original description in Ash's Pokedex read:

> *Arcanine, **a Legendary Pokémon**. The evolved form of Growlithe. Arcanine
>   is known for its bravery and fierce loyalty. Growlithe evolves into
>   Arcanine from its use of a Fire Stone.*

---

Bottom left is a [Zapdos](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Zapdos_(Pok%C3%A9mon))

[image]

Bottom right is an [Arcanine](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Arcanine_(Pok%C3%A9mon))

[image]

Top left is a [Moltres](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Moltres_(Pok%C3%A9mon))

[image]

And the Top right is an [Articuno](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Articuno_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), mis-identified by Ash as an [Ho-oh](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ho-Oh_(Pok%C3%A9mon)).

[image]

Comment: I would clarify that they're the 4 Legendary Pokemon known to the in-universe public at the time of that episode. Even the [original batch had other legendary Pokemon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Legendary_Pok%C3%A9mon#Generation_I): Mew and Mewtwo.

Comment: @CreationEdge - You're half right. Mewtwo was Legendary, Mew was Mythical. But edited accordingly.

Comment: According to the article I linked to, that's just an additional distinction. That terminology isn't clearly defined even in Poke circles, but a common interpretation is that Mythical Pokemon *are* legendary (thus being listed on that link). Mythical is a subclass of Legendary. At the top of the same article: "There is also a group considered to be a **subset of Legendary Pokémon, referred to as 神話のポケモン mythical Pokémon**, which lacks an official English name and refers to the specific Pokémon which are spoken of as the creators of the Sinnoh region."

Comment: @CreationEdge - I don't know enough about the subsequent series' to pass comment. Possibly that's worthy of its own question.

Comment: I don't know about the newer stuff, myself. I do know that during the original Pokemon boom no one ever used the term "Mythical", that seems to be a newer addition. Whether it was the GB games or the TCG, there were 5 legendarie (it was just trivia that Arcanine's *species* was referred to as Legendary) and most of use could only get 4 in game (until we got a GameShark or Monster Brain).

Comment: Actually you are wrong Nintendo first gave Zapdos,Articuno and Arcanine as the legendary trio.
But they removed Arcanine as it would have been awkward.Two birds and a dog,huh!
The mythical thing is right BTW.

Comment: Why was Arcanine there? I mean, he's 'The Legendary Pokemon' but not ***a*** legendary Pokémon

Comment: @Jack - Worthy of its own question

Comment: Well, I better get on it! :)

Comment: I don't recall anyone ever counting Arcanine as a Legendary pokemon in Gen 1. The games certainly don't treat it as one. Gen 1 legendaries were the birds + Mew/two. Is there any actual word from Nintendo/GF on this?

Comment: @DavidS - ["Why was Arcanine with the Legendary Birds in Veridian City in Pokémon Origins?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142662/why-was-arcanine-with-the-legendary-birds-in-veridian-city-in-pok%c3%a9mon-origins?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Valorum the accepted answer just seems to repeat the assertion that Arcanine was originally meant to be a Legendary, but doesn't give any sources for the claim. Weird. All I can find is that some Pokedex entries claim it is a legendary pokemon in China(!?) which just raises more questions :P

Comment: @DavidS - It was referred to as "*Arcanine, a Legendary Pokémon. The evolved form of Growlithe. Arcanine is known for its bravery and fierce loyalty. Growlithe evolves into Arcanine from its use of a Fire Stone.*" in the original series (EP 190) and as "*A legendary Pokémon in China. Many people are charmed by its grace and beauty while running.*" in Pokemon Yellow on the gameboy. By the time they got to Gen 2, they'd corrected that to "*This legendary Chinese Pokémon is considered magnificent. Many people are enchanted by its grand mane.*"

Comment: @Valorum Good summary. Thing is, all the psuedo-Legendary references seem to come post-anime (including Yellow), while in Gen 1 there's no mention at all of Arcanine being anything other than a normal Pokemon. People keep saying it's a reference to when Arcanine was going to be a Legendary, but then they aren't citing pre-anime stuff, which is what we need to actually establish the original intent.

Comment: Arcanine's category is "The Legendary Pokémon." All Pokémon have categories, a kind of extra name, though sometimes shared amongst Pokémon - Pikachu is "The Mouse Pokémon", Machop is "The Superpower Pokémon" etc. (These were formerly known as the Pokémon's species). Arcanine just happens to be "The Legendary Pokémon." According to its 'dex entries it has a lot of legends told about it - so as well as being The Legendary Pokémon, it is a legendary Pokémon. But not a Legendary Pokémon. If that makes sense!