# Was Arcanine originally intended to be a Legendary Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon

In [these](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84512/who-are-the-pok%c3%a9mon-on-the-decoration-in-the-viridian-city-pok%c3%a9mon-center?noredirect=1&lq=1) [questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142662/why-was-arcanine-with-the-legendary-birds-in-veridian-city-in-pok%C3%A9mon-origins?noredirect=1&lq=1) it was repeatedly suggested that Arcanine was intended to be a Legendary, hence being included in the tablet with the birds and the weird Pokedex entries.

The only hint of this in Gen 1 is it's category ("Legendary") but these appear to be more like descriptors of the Pokemon, rather than classifications (the other Gen 1 Legendaries do not have the category "Legendary").

The Pokedex entries up to Stadium are as follows.

> Red and Blue: A Pokémon that has been admired since the past for its beauty. It runs agilely as if on wings.
>
> Yellow: A legendary Pokémon in China. Many people are charmed by its grace and beauty while running.
>
> Stadium: A Pokémon whose beauty is legendary in China. It is said to run gracefully and lightly, as if it were flying.

It seems like there are two possible explanations.

1. It was not intended to be Legendary, but the makers of the anime misunderstood the category and so included Arcanine in with the actual Legendaries (the Birds and Mew/two). In Yellow onwards GameFreak made sure to clarify that it was more like a historically worshiped/popular Pokemon in China, rather than an actual Legendary.
2. It was originally intended to be Legendary, but this was removed from Gen 1 at the last minute and remnants of this can be seen in the anime.

Do we have any confirmation of either of these explanations from GameFreak/Nintendo/the makers of the anime? Or is there another explanation that has evidentiary support?

---

This question is about **the original intent of Arcanine**, not [why it's included with the Legendaries within a specific shot of Pokemon Origins](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142662/why-was-arcanine-with-the-legendary-birds-in-veridian-city-in-pok%C3%A9mon-origins?noredirect=1&lq=1). The accepted answer to that question simply points to an earlier shot of the anime, says "to match this" (which is technically correct) and then **reiterates the claim that my question is asking about. My question is about the claim itself and whether any support for it exists.**

Comment: By the way, if the answer is (1) then you can just rationalise the tablet away by saying it was foreshadowing the Legendary Beasts, and that the artist just drew a dog Pokemon like one that they already knew ;)

Comment: I always wondered why Arcanine had such abnormally high base stats for a non-(pseudo) legendary Pokemon. Perhaps this is why.

Comment: Woah, hold up, this is not a dupe. My question is about the original intent of Arcanine, the other question asks why it's included with the Legendaries within a specific shot of Pokemon Origins (and the accepted answer simply points to an earlier shot of the anime and then reiterates the claim that my question is trying to dig into). The two answers may or may not be related, we won't know **until mine is answered** (this problem is actually discussed in the comments of the "dupe" question).

Comment: Note: this duplicate issue seems to be a letter/spirit of the law thing. The accepted answer to the "dupe" question is *technically* correct, but does not answer the actual, implicit question that the writer was really asking (I repeat, **this is flagged as a problem in the comments of the "dupe"**).  My question here is making that *implicit* question *explicit* and fleshing it out.

Comment: @DavidS _"this duplicate issue seems to be a letter/spirit of the law thing"_ - I don't think that's the case, I personally misread the questions when I cast my close vote. On reflection this is clearly building off of the other question (not sure how I missed that to be honest) and so I have cast a reopen vote.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Just to clarify, since I don't think I explained too well - I meant that the spirit of the other question *is this question*, but the exact wording they used (the letter) made it easy to answer without actually answering.

Comment: @DavidS The other question hints at this question but appears to be asking why in that instance alone, which the answer is it's a callback/reference which obviously would not answer this question. I can see how I got confused the first time around but re-reading I certainly don't think they are dupes.